# RS232, RS422 Splitter-- EDIT fot JTAG

Tags: rs232, jtag, rs422

Is it good to use one UART interface on MCU, RX_UART for receiving data from RS422 receiver and TX_UART for transmitting the same data to the RS232 and RS422 transmitter? I am trying to use UART as "signal splitter", because I want to use my rs422 input signal and forward it to rs232 and other rs422.

EDIT:
I can not ask another question, and don't know how to edit others to be allowed to ask again, but I would like to know this:

Why JTAG connectors use 20, 14 or 10 pins (standard), when only 7 is required (minimum, TDI, TDO, TMS, TCK, NTRS, GND, VDD)?

Comment: That seems a little unclear.  Your finished system will have what inputs and outputs?

Comment: It would have RS422/485 input (one receiver), and outputs RS422 and RS232 (one driver for each).

Comment: Why do you need a UART at all? Just connect the receiver directly to the two drivers.

Comment: I could do that, but I also need received data to process in MCU. Maybe I should connect both drivers and MCU to receiver. Thank you.

Comment: Right, that's what I would do. One RS422 differential receiver connected to RS422 transmitter, RS232 transmitter, and the Rx input pin on your MCU.

Comment: There would be one advantage of using the UART transmitter to echo the incoming data (assuming you don't need it for anything else): If the input signal is noisy or jittery, the signal you transmit would be a "cleaned-up" copy of the data that doesn't propagate those problems.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you, that is also what I thought, but was not sure about echo delay and maybe possibility to use data for further ethernet communication.

Comment: Don't use the UART transmitter, is the sending clock even 0.1% fast you may get buffer overruns because you will not be able to send fast enough to keep up with what you receive.

Comment: @Jasen: That's true only if the source is sending continuous data with absolutely no gaps at all -- very rare. But yes, some amount of buffering would be a good idea.

Comment: @Haris778: ??? What does Ethernet have to do with this? This is the first you've mentioned it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I would like to send received data over ethernet. So, if I am going to use UART echo for transmitting data to RS232 and RS422 transmitters, that might be problem, but than I could use UART just for receiving data (not echo) and connect receiving side directly to RS232 and RS422 transmitters. There are three solutions, either use UART TX for echo, or use just UART RX and than process data and send it over ethernet, or use UART echo simultaneously with processing data.

Comment: I still don't understand why transmitting the data over Ethernet would have any effect on whether or not you use the UART transmitter to echo the data. What is the problem with the third option?

Comment: @DaveTweed Processing time, isn't that a problem. I need to echo received data and read it from input buffer.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Transferring a byte between a software buffer and a hardware UART (in either direction) is a rather trivial operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no problem
connecting a output to several inputs is normal, the limit is the fan out
If you use MAX488 as a repeater of RS422 (connect DO to DI), you can connect a MAX232 Tx Input to the TTL side of MAX488 (DO + DI).